# Why this "Implicit declaration of function 'X'"?

Tags: c, function, compiler-warnings

I wrote a simple program to find the Sum, average, biggest and smallest number of 3 numbers.
It lets the user to input three (integer) numbers and return the sum, average, max and min.
It has no errors but a warning. Here is my source code:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, sum, max, min, avg;

    printf("Enter Three \"Integer\" Numbers:");

    scanf("%i%i%i", &num1, &num2, &num3);

    sum = summation(&num1, &num2, &num3);
    avg = average(&sum);
    max = max_val(&num1, &num2, &num3);
    min = min_val(&num1, &num2, &num3);

    printf("Sum: %i Avg: %i MAX: %i MIN: %i", sum, avg, max, min);

    return 0;
}

int summation(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3)
{
    int s;
    s = *n1 + *n2 + *n3;

    return s;
}

int average(int *s)
{
    int a;
    a = *s / 3;

    return a;
}

int max_val(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3)
{
    int MAX;

    if (*n1 > *n2) MAX = *n1;
    else if (*n2 > *n3) MAX = *n2;
    else MAX = *n3;

    return MAX;
}

int min_val(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3)
{
    int MIN;

    if (*n1 < *n2) MIN = *n1;
    else if (*n2 < *n3) MIN = *n2;
    else MIN = *n3;

    return MIN;
}
```

I think there is no need to make a header file because all functions are in type of "int".

When I compile this

```
gcc main.c -o test
```

It says

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:34:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'summation' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Why this warning? I can't find any wrong in that declaration.
What's that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`summation` and your other functions are defined *after* they're used in `main`, and so the compiler has made a guess about it's signature; in other words, an *implicit declaration* has been assumed.

You should declare the function before it's used and get rid of the warning. In the C99 specification, this is an error.

Either move the function bodies *before* `main`, or include method signatures before `main`, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int summation(int *, int *, int *);

int main()
{
    // ...
```

Comment: ah, yeah, I got it. That means it should be broken into .c pieces and compile them together, no? Thank you!

Comment: @0xEDD1E More specifically, it's like a book. You read from top to bottom. If you read the bottom before the top, you don't understand the plot. Same goes for C and C++ programs. Everything must literally be defined prior to use... variables, functions, structs, enums, etc.

Comment: In the 1990 version of the C standard, there's an implicit declaration and the function is assumed to return `int`. In the 1999 version and later, there is no "implicit int" rule; calling a function with no visible declaration is a constraint violation.